# Consider defining a bean of type 'service' in your configuration [Spring boot]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I get error when I run the main class.

**Error:**

```
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'seconds47.service.TopicService' in your configuration.

Description:
Field topicService in seconds47.restAPI.topics required a bean of type 'seconds47.service.TopicService' that could not be found
```

TopicService interface:

```
public interface TopicService {

    TopicBean findById(long id);

    TopicBean findByName(String name);

    void saveTopic(TopicBean topicBean);

    void updateTopic(TopicBean topicBean);

    void deleteTopicById(long id);

    List<TopicBean> findAllTopics(); 

    void deleteAllTopics();

    public boolean isTopicExist(TopicBean topicBean);
}
```

controller:

```
@RestController
public class topics {

    @Autowired
    private TopicService topicService;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/new_topic2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void new_topic() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("new topic JAVA2");
    }
}
```

Implementation class:

```
public class TopicServiceImplementation implements TopicService {

    @Autowired
    private TopicService topicService;

    @Autowired
    private TopicRepository topicRepository;

    @Override
    public TopicBean findById(long id) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public TopicBean findByName(String name) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void saveTopic(TopicBean topicBean) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void updateTopic(TopicBean topicBean) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteTopicById(long id) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public List<TopicBean> findAllTopics() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAllTopics() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTopicExist(TopicBean topicBean) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Rest of the classes are defined too. I don't know why its throwing despite declaring `componentScan` in main class.

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"seconds47"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("seconds47.repository")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have my packages like this:

```
seconds47
seconds47.beans
seconds47.config
seconds47.repository
seconds47.restAPI
seconds47.service
```

Comment: Does the class `TopicServiceImplementation` have the annotation `@Component`? If not, you have to add it to the class, so that Spring can recognize it as a bean.

Comment: @dunni In spring boot, `@Component` annotation is not required it is scanned automatically by springboot unlike springmvc

Comment: If you don't add any annotation on the class, it is not scanned, because you haven't marked it as a bean. If you don't believe me, read the documentation.

Comment: @dunni you are right. I would accept it as answer. thanks

Answer (score 67, accepted):

A class must have the `@Component` annotation or a derivation of that (like `@Service`, `@Repository` etc.) to be recognized as a Spring bean by the component scanning. So if you add `@Component` to the class, it should solve your problem.

Comment: I am getting that error even if I have annotated that class with @Component

Comment: @TusharBanne it will not work if you use annotation for interface of bean, not for bean

Answer (score 13):

I fixed the problem adding this line `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.DemoApplication"})` to main class file, just up from the class name

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.DemoApplication"})
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 12):

Since `TopicService` is a `Service` class, you should annotate it with `@Service`, so that Spring autowires this bean for you. Like so:

```
@Service
public class TopicServiceImplementation implements TopicService {
    ...
}
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this issue by creating a bean for my service in SpringConfig.java file.
Please check the below code,

```
@Configuration 
public class SpringConfig { 

@Bean
public TransactionService transactionService() {
    return new TransactionServiceImpl();
}

}
```

The path of this file is shown in the below image,
[Spring boot application folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zCzp.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

> Consider defining a bean of type 
>      'moviecruser.repository.MovieRepository' in your 
>       configuration.

This type of issue will generate if you did not add 
   correct dependency. Its the same issue I faced but after I found my JPA 
   dependency is not working correctly, so make sure that first 
   dependency is correct or not.

For example:-

The  dependency I used:

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>      
       <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Description (got this exception):-

> Parameter 0 of constructor in 
>       moviecruser.serviceImple.MovieServiceImpl required a bean of 
>       type 'moviecruser.repository.MovieRepository' that could not 
>        be found.

Action:

After change dependency:-

```
    <!-- 
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Response:-

> 2019-09-06 23:08:23.202  INFO 7780 -
>          [main]moviecruser.MovieCruserApplication]:Started 
>          MovieCruserApplication in 10.585 seconds (JVM running for 
>        11.357)

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to inject a bean in itself. That's obviously not going to work.

`TopicServiceImplementation` implements `TopicService`. That class attempts to autowire (by field!) a `TopicService. So you're essentially asking the context to inject itself.

It looks like you've edited the content of the error message: `Field topicService in seconds47.restAPI.topics` is not a class. Please be careful if you need to hide sensitive information as it makes it much harder for others to help you.

Back on the actual issue, it looks like injecting `TopicService` in itself is a glitch on your side.

Comment: I didn't understand a thing when you said `I am injecting a bean in itself` ?? I am injecting `TopicService` which is a interface into a controller class `Topics`

Comment: I didn't edit the error message. I just edited the question title I have posted

Comment: Still the problem exists. I removed `@Autowired
    private TopicService topicService;` from implementation class

Answer (score 4):

In case you were wondering where to add `@Service` annotation, then
make sure you have added `@Service` annotation to the **class** **that implements the interface**. That would solve this problem.

Comment: @Service annotation I applied on the interface  that's why I was facing the same problem, after applying it on implementation class it worked for me

Answer (score 3):

You have to update your

```
scanBasePackages = { "com.exm.java" }
```

to add the path to your service (after annotating it with @service )

Answer (score 3):

I resolved by replacing the corrupted jar files.

But to find those corrupted jar files, I have to run my application in three IDE- 1) Intellij Idea 2)NetBeans 3) Eclipse.

Netbeans given me information for maximum number of corrupted jar. In Netbeans along with the run, I use the build option(after right clicking on project) to know more about corrupted jars.

It took me more than 15 hours to find out the root cause for these errors. Hope it help anyone.

Answer (score 2):

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"io.testapi"})

In the main class below springbootapplication annotation i have written componentscan and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Even after doing all the method suggested, i was getting the same error. After trying  hard, i got to know that hibernate's maven dependency was added in my pom.xml, as i removed it, application started successfully.

I removed this dependency:

```
<dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
             <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
         </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just have this issue and this is the solution. Firstly, create an interface as below:

```
public interface TransactionService {

}
```

Then implement the methods using a class:

```
@Service
public class TransactionServiceImpl implements TransactionService {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have added the dependency in pom.xml or gradle file

spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

Answer (score 0):

I once ran into a similar problem. You can annotate the service class with `@Component` and the `@SpringBootApplication` at Main should carry `@SpringBootApplication(ScanBasePackages="com.seconds47")`