# Spring : Unsatisfied dependency

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Learning Springboot to create a simple project.Initially i tried mocking DAO using fake data in `hashsets`, all was fine, moving to actual DAO - all hell broke loose.

At present i am trying to fetch certain data from table but its not working, [tried all possible SO threads](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException%3A%20Error%20creating%20bean%20with%20name&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=G8rGWcvAM6by8AfqoKf4CQ), did `scanBasePackages` set to my `com.base.project` as well, nothing is helping.Hence resorting to last hope.

Also, apart from error if you want to suggest correction in the code flow, please do tell....any kind of learning is welcome! :)

**Controller class**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/movies")

public class MovieController {

    @Autowired
    private MovieServices movieServices;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Collection<Movie> getAllMovies(){
        return movieServices.getAllMovies();
    }
}
```

**Service Class**

```
@Service // annotation needed to be recongnised as a bean - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41663652/consider-defining-a-bean-of-type-service-in-your-configuration-spring-boot
public class MovieServices {

    @Autowired // help avoid 'new' keyword on every call
    private MovieDao movies;

    public MovieServices(){}

    public Collection<Movie> getAllMovies(){
        return movies.findByInCinemas(true);

    }

}
```

**Entity Class**

```
@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
public class Movie {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="movieId")
    private int movieId;
    private String title;
    private String language;
    private String genre;
    private boolean inCinemas;

    public Movie(int id, String title, String language, String genre, boolean inCinemas) {
        this.movieId = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.language = language;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.inCinemas = inCinemas;
    }

    public boolean isInCinemas() {
        return inCinemas;
    }

    public void setInCinemas(boolean inCinemas) {
        this.inCinemas = inCinemas;
    }


    public int getMovieId() {
        return movieId;
    }

    public void setMovieId(int movieId) {
        this.movieId = movieId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }
}
```

**DAO class**

```
@Repository
public interface MovieDao extends CrudRepository<Movie, Long>{
//    private static Map<Integer, Movie> movies;

//    @Autowired
//    GenericDao genericDao;


    // custom query example and return a stream
    @Query("select * from movie where in_cinemas = :in_cinemas")
    List<Movie> findByInCinemas(@Param("in_cinemas") boolean inCinemas);


}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-09-24 02:16:15.587 ERROR 71250 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'movieController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'movieServices'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'movieServices': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'movies'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'movieDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.interview.intuit.Dao.MovieDao.findByInCinemas(boolean)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at com.interview.intuit.Main.main(Main.java:16) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'movieServices': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'movies'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'movieDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.interview.intuit.Dao.MovieDao.findByInCinemas(boolean)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'movieDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.interview.intuit.Dao.MovieDao.findByInCinemas(boolean)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.interview.intuit.Dao.MovieDao.findByInCinemas(boolean)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:62) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:72) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:53) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:212) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:221) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 8 [select * from movie where in_cinemas = :in_cinemas]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1679) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:294) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy80.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 8 [select * from movie where in_cinemas = :in_cinemas]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:288) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:187) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1894) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 67 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? You provided an explicit JPA query that is SQL, not JPQL. (Additionally, Spring Data will autogenerate that query for you.)

Comment: hey, hi....yes i did read the message.Unfortunately couldn't co-relate that error pointing to `controller` is actually co-related to `DAO`.... should i  remove the SQL and just let function definition stay!?

Comment: so i removed the query and changed function definition to `List<Movie> findByInCinemas(boolean inCinemas);` ... it compiles fine but no output on the api....just an empty list!

Comment: @NoobEditor btw in Spring you should usually look at the last exception `QuerySyntaxException` and not first `UnsatisfiedDependencyException`. Yeah, i also had hard times figuring this out). If something goes wrong you can get all kinds of exceptions) But the wrong part usually in the first thrown exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that your Query is incorrect JPQL.

```
@Query("select * from movie where in_cinemas = :in_cinemas")
```

Probably can use something like

```
 @Query("select t from Movie t where t.inCinemas = ?1")
 List<Movie> findByInCinemas(boolean inCinemas);
```

Important to note that JPQL wants your class and class should be always with big character (`Movie`) at begining. And if your movie class looks like

```
@Entity
@Data  // lombok.Data
public class Movie {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="in_cinemas")
    private boolean inCinemas;
}
```

you actually need to give class field name `inCinemas` and not table name `in_cinemas`

---

But for such simple cases Spring has its method name convention, so you could actually use

```
@Repository
public interface MovieDao extends CrudRepository<Movie, Long> {
    List<Movie> findAllByInCinemas(boolean inCinemas);
}
```

Comment: yup..it works!!
One question, out of loop, i have a box office class which refers to Movies - Box office can have many movies but movies are independent (meaning no reverse mapping to box office).How do i present this in Spring? `@OneToMany @JoinColumn(name="movieId") private List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();`  binds movies to have a screen which is worng!

Comment: @NoobEditor if i got your question right, you have db structure with 3 tables like `movie`, `box`, `box_movie` and you don't want Movie class to know anything about Box? You can still use `@OneToMany` in `Box`, but just ignore `@ManyToOne` from the opposite side in `Movie` class ` and provide no field there. To be honest i think it is preferred to use `@...Many` annotations only if you really need and going to query them.

Comment: possible to give me 10 mins? => https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155170/spring-issues

Answer (score 1):

Your query should meet JPQL syntax. Please check the code below:

```
@Query("select m from Movie m where m.inCinemas = :in_cinemas")
List<Movie> findByInCinemas(@Param("in_cinemas") boolean inCinemas);
```

Comment: hello....it gives same error still `org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'movieController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'movieServices';` ... when i commented the query part, its is compiling all right.check my comment above! :)

Comment: sorry...my bad...1 min!!

Comment: I fixed query part from `m.in_cinemas` to `m.inCinemas`. Should work now,  as in JPQL you're referring to the class field instead of a table field. But actually [varren's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1032167/varren) answer is more detailed ))

Comment: its working....can you answer one last out of loop question? i posted in varren's answer!

Answer (score 1):

Though it already has an answer to resolve the issue.

For this very simple scenario, we actually dont require `@Query` to create custom query. Let spring data to do his magic, All you need is this

```
@Repository
public interface MovieDao extends CrudRepository<Movie, Long>{


    List<Movie> findByInCinemas(boolean inCinemas);


}
```

Even `@Repository` is not required in the latest versions.

Secondly, Make use of `JpaRepository<Movie,Long>` than `CrudRepository` as it provides more jpa related methods to play with.

Docs for keywords :

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest creating interface for MovieServices and inject typeof interface in controller not concrete class directly